# Is it possible to implement question #171 on Leetcode recursively?

Tags: python

I'm doing [question #171 "Excel Sheet Column Number" on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-number/). And the only way I could think of is to do it recursively.

Here's my attempt in Python:

```
class Solution:
    def titleToNumber(self, s) -> int:
        myDict = {
            'A': 1,
            'B': 2,
            'C': 3,
            'D': 4,
            'E': 5,
            'F': 6,
            'G': 7,
            'H': 8,
            'I': 9,
            'J': 10,
            'K': 11,
            'L': 12,
            'M': 13,
            'N': 14,
            'O': 15,
            'P': 16,
            'Q': 17,
            'R': 18,
            'S': 19,
            'T': 20,
            'U': 21,
            'V': 22,
            'W': 23,
            'X': 24,
            'Y': 25,
            'Z': 26,
        }
        if len(s) == 1:
            return myDict[s]
        else:
            return myDict[s[0:1]] * 26 + self.titleToNumber(s[1:])
```

The problem I have is that I can't get the str without the first letter after the second time calling the function itself recursively.

Comment: You don't need the last line from your code. Comment out `s = s[1:]` and your code seems to work fine. Also please don't use built-in/pre-defined name such as `dict`, as the variable name.

Comment: Thank you!. Oh, I actually added in the last line just to play with it. But it wouldn't work with anything more than three letters like AAA or AAAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified `myDict` and slightly modified recursion.

```
class Solution:
    def titleToNumber(self, s) -> int:
        my_map = lambda x: ord(x) - ord('A') + 1
        char = s[-1]
        s = s[:-1]
        if not s:
            # s originally was a single-character
            return my_map(char)
        else:
            return 26 * self.titleToNumber(s) + my_map(char)
```

Say, the we want to convert `AB` to digit. It means that we have 2 more than 26 columns, i.e., `my_map('A') * 26 + my_map('B')`. Now, let's convert `ABC` to integer. If we separate `C`, we need to convert `AB` to number at multiply by 26. Then, I add the value of `C`. I get the recursion formula:
`titleToNumber(s) = 26 * titleToNumber(s[:-1]) + my_map(s[-1]).`